# Spring Boot pages/views works when running from IntelliJ, but when running from .jar I get a blank page for any url/request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, tomcat

When I run the project through IDE (Intellij) all pages, mvc, controllers work fine, but when I compile the executable (package) and run it with the same JDK, I get blank pages, and Spring Boot sees that I'm trying to access a certain page, but then it redirects to ErrorController right away

The log of.jar

```
2023-08-21T09:29:11.495+06:00 DEBUG 468841 --- [io-10000-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.example.emailcalendarjava.controller.PPWController#showmyPPWList(Model, Principal)
2023-08-21T09:29:11.546+06:00 DEBUG 468841 --- [io-10000-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.example.emailcalendarjava.controller.ErrorController#handleError(HttpServletRequest, Model)
```

in Intellij:

```
2023-08-21T09:51:11.149+06:00 DEBUG 4728 --- [io-10000-exec-7] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [resources/], classpath [static/], classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]
2023-08-21T09:51:11.150+06:00 DEBUG 4728 --- [io-10000-exec-7] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [resources/], classpath [static/], classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]
2023-08-21T09:51:11.150+06:00 DEBUG 4728 --- [io-10000-exec-7] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [resources/], classpath [static/], classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]
2023-08-21T09:51:11.151+06:00 DEBUG 4728 --- [io-10000-exec-7] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [resources/], classpath [static/], classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]
2023-08-21T09:51:11.152+06:00 DEBUG 4728 --- [io-10000-exec-7] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [resources/], classpath [static/], classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]
2023-08-21T09:51:11.152+06:00 DEBUG 4728 --- [io-10000-exec-7] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [resources/], classpath [static/], classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]
2023-08-21T09:51:11.153+06:00 DEBUG 4728 --- [io-10000-exec-7] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [resources/], classpath [static/], classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]
2023-08-21T09:51:11.153+06:00 DEBUG 4728 --- [io-10000-exec-7] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/favicon.ico", parameters={}
2023-08-21T09:51:11.154+06:00 DEBUG 4728 --- [io-10000-exec-7] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [resources/], classpath [static/], classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]
2023-08-21T09:51:11.167+06:00 DEBUG 4728 --- [io-10000-exec-7] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
```

Attempts to change library versions, security configuration, tomcat settings (now I use as before embedded without additional settings) did not give any result. Set Error contrloeer to default is also not give result.

my pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>EmailCalendarJava</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>EmailCalendarJava</name>
    <description>EmailCalendarJava</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-envers</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-audit-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6</artifactId>
            <!-- Temporary explicit version to fix Thymeleaf bug -->
            <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>BeeTasks</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>
                        true
                    </executable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

The main file

```java
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
//@SpringBootApplication
@SpringBootConfiguration
@EnableScheduling
@ComponentScan  //(basePackages = "com.example.emailcalendarjava")
public class EmailCalendarJavaApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(SpringApplicationBuilder.class);
    }
    public static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmailCalendarJavaApplication.class);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EmailCalendarJavaApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

One of the example of my controller

```java
@Controller
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class PPWController {
    private final SomeServices someServices;

    @GetMapping("/show")
    public String show(Model model, Principal principal) {... returm "template"}
```

Security (II'm not sure if it's a security issue, but just in case, I'll put it here too.)

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class EndToEndSecurityDemo {

    private final EndToEndUserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider(){
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authenticationProvider;
    }
   @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/api/**").denyAll()
                .requestMatchers(
                        "/",
                        "/login",
                        "/error",
                        "/registration/**",
                        "/public-img/**",
                        "favicon.ico"

                )
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()

                .and()

                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .usernameParameter("email")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                .permitAll()

                .and()
                .logout()
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .clearAuthentication(true)
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .and()
                .build()
                ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after two days of searching for the problem I created an empty project and started to manually move all files and set dependencies manually and it worked, as I realized in the library directory accumulated several versions of the same libraries that were taken into account when compiling the package and because of them did not load pages, I realized this by the size of the compiled file before and after (was 98mb, became 60mb, the code is the same).